# CSS - two divs next to each other, 100% width and overflow

Tags: html, css

I want to have two divs next to each other. Not too hard right?

Yeah...

I can do things like `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;`, but I also want the divs to be `width: 100%` but as soon I do that they get displayed below each other.

To better illustrate what I want I have drawn this:

[image]

As you can see `child div 1` is visible inside the parent(`overflow: hidden;`) and `child div 2` is not because they both have a width of 100%.

Now, my question is: How would I accomplish this?

I have already tried a lot of things but almost everything ends up placing the divs below each other.

Comment: To have both of them have width 100%, you would have to give their parents a width of 50% each.

Comment: there is only one parent.

Comment: You could use `display: flex` on the parent, but then the width on the children doesn't mean anything. Is that what you want?

Comment: Okay, I have a question: My question is put on hold and it has 4 down votes. What is so bad/wrong about my question? I got more than enough answers, and even from @Nisarg that said my question was "unclear". But if it's that unclear why do you answer correctly?

Comment: Regarding the closure, I see the following problems with the question: (1) Why you want both div's to have 100% width isn't clear. Based on your accepted answer, perhaps you want both div's to have the width of 100vw - which is different from 100%. (2) You haven't provided any code demonstrating your attempt(s). If you had, it might have helped us understand your requirement better. You can still [edit] and improve your question, and we can reopen it if it appears clear after that.

Comment: You can also reach out to Meta if you are not satisfied with my comments. Hopefully others can provider better suggestions.

Comment: Hmmmm... okay, thanks for letting me know. I will try to be more clear next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the parent to be 200% of the body width. Then the children need to be half the parents width i.e. 50%, like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 200%;
}

.container .pane {
  width: 50%;
  background: #eee;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="pane">
    Pane 1
  </div>
  <div class="pane">
    Pane 2
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works best.

Comment: Flexbox would be better, less code, no floats.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `position: relative` and `position: absolute` properties to achieve what you want. Try using this code.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">child 2</div>
</div>
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
.child1 {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.child2 {
  width: 100%;
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few ways to do it but if you have a container for them and use flex, u can then set flex:1 on both those divs and they will sit next to eachother and you wont need to use floats.  Each will get half of the parent.

Comment: You should atleast give OP code.

Comment: I could habe but i took his question literal.  "How would I accomplish this".  If he would like an example of how flexbox works i will provide one.